# PHP CURL sending POST to Django app issue

Tags: php, python, django, curl

This code in PHP sends a HTTP POST to a Django app using CURL lib.

I need that this code sends POST but redirect to the page in the same submit. Like a simple form does.

The PHP Code:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.xxx.com");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Var='.$var);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

In this case, the PHP is sending the HTTP POST, but is not redirecting to the page. He is printing the result. My URL still .php and not a django/url/

I need be redirected to the django URL with the Post like a simple form in HTML does.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does a server-side POST request to the page. You can't "redirect" the user to the same "instance" of the page.

If you need to do it in one step, print out a form with method="POST" and hidden fields and then add JavaScript which automatically submits it.

Comment: Nice.
I worked in this solution and its working fine.

I just dont know for how long lol.